# 1053 error info when to convert bat into a service

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-services

I want to convert bat file into a service:

```
gvim  c:\myapp.bat
c:\myapp.exe -c c:\config.json
```

It contain only one command,it runs fine when i double click the myapp.bat.
Convert it into a service with sc command:

```
C:\Windows\system32>sc  create myapp  binpath= c:\myapp.bat
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS
```

[image]
It encounter an 1053 error when to start it.

[image]

I google search and do as the webpage say:
[solve 1053 error](https://ugetfix.com/ask/fix-error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashion/)

[image]

Reboot my pc ,the problem can't solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting [error 1053](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#Error1053) because your batch file is not a "true" Windows Service — even though you added it with SC and it shows up in the Services application.

To function properly, a Windows Service must implement the [Services API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-functions). Since your batch file does not implement that API, you will need a "wrapper" application to run your batch file as a service. The [free "SRVANY" utility from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/create-user-defined-service) may work for you but you should investigate the more fully-featured commercial alternatives as well.